# how can i get to the li in the ul?

Tags: jquery, html

I have nested `divs` and `ul`, how can I get to the `li` inside the `ul` using the class.
If I click the image with `id="id1"`, I want to go the `<li>` `-->` `<img>` with `class="c1"`.

html:

```
<div class="1">
    <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
            <img id="id1" src="">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="c1">
                <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="c2">
                <a href="#"><img src="img.png"/></a>
            </li>
            <li class="c3">
                <a href="#"><imgsrc="img.png"/></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#'+id1 ).parent().children()[2].find('li.c2').html();
```

I tried this... but didn't work... any help :)

Comment: What's the `id1` in the jQuery function? a variable? Or you just trying to grab the ID of the element? Why not just use #id1??

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$('#'+id1 ).parent().nextSibling().find('li.c2').html();
```

But wouldn't it be easier to add an id to the `<ul>`?

BTW, you can't start class names with a number, as in `<div class="3">`.

Comment: For `<ul id='myUl'>` use `$("#myUl li.c2).html()`